# Leading zero for printing dates and strange behaviour

Tags: javascript

I prepared a function to put a leading zero for padding number with one single digit:

```
function pretty_time_string(num) {
    return ( num < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + num;
}
```

Then I call it every time I need, expecially to print dates and times using this:

```
function printHMS(d){
    if (!(d instanceof Date)) d = new Date(d);
    return d.getHours() + ":" 
    + pretty_time_string(d.getMinutes()) + ":" +
        + pretty_time_string(d.getSeconds());
}
```

Now I see a strange behaviour in calling the first function directly or through my second function:

```
d = new Date(1429082763978);
document.body.innerHTML = 'Why this is with leading zero: '
    + pretty_time_string(d.getSeconds())
    + '<br>And this not? ' + printHMS(d);
```

The result is this: https://jsfiddle.net/gbh4xq9e/1/

```
Why this is with leading zero: 03
And this not? 9:26:3
```

I really cannot figure out why this strange behaviour

**UPDATE 1:**
I tried also this: https://jsfiddle.net/gbh4xq9e/3/

```
d.setMinutes(1);
document.body.innerHTML += '<br>UPDATE 1:<br>What about minutes? '
    +  printHMS(d);
```

and seems that the result has a leading zero for the minutes, but not for seconds.

Comment: You don't pass `d.getHours()` to `pretty_time_string()` in `printHMS`.

Comment: @Sacho But they pass d.getSeconds() to it, which is their point.

Comment: @ tyranitar: Be careful of that habit of continuing expressions with the operator at the beginning of the next line (rather than at the end of the previous line): Automatic Semicolon Insertion can kick in. (It doesn't here, just a general warning.)

Comment: @Crowder thank you! I am going to follow your advise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a double + in the `printHMS`-function converting the string "03" to the number 3 before concatinating.

Both of the following statements are true:

```
"3:26:" + + "03" === "3:26:3"
"3:26:" + "03"   === "3:26:03"
```

Thus the `printHMS`-function could be

```
function printHMS(d){
    if (!(d instanceof Date)) d = new Date(d);
    return d.getHours() + ":" +
        pretty_time_string(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + 
        pretty_time_string(d.getSeconds());
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/gbh4xq9e/4/ for full working code.